# What is the effect of this delayed statement in the following process?

Tags: vhdl, delay, process

Hi guys in the following process how the delayed assignment should be interpreted?

```
clk_process : process
begin
        clk <= '0','1' after 5 ns;
        wait for 10 ns;
end process;
```

Is it intepreted as...

clk is set to '0' for 5 ns then i changes into '1' and after 10 ns it is set again to '0'?
or it is simply '0' for 5 ns and '1' for 5 ns?

I'm a bit confused...

Comment: You can shorten it to `clk <= not clk after 5 ns;` :).

Comment: you're right xD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process has no sensitivity list, and a wait statement. It will therefore run repeatedly. The following stages can be seen:

- Time = 0; set `clk` to `'0'`, with a delayed assignment to `'1'` after 5 ns.
- Start 10 ns wait.
- Time = 5 ns. perform delayed assignment to `'1'`.
- Time = 10 ns, wait statement has completed.
- Go back to the start of the process

The end result is a clock, starting at `'0'`, with a period of 10 ns.

Comment: So it is (0,0 ns), (1, 5 ns), (0, 10 ns), (1, 15 ns), ... and so on?

Comment: A 15 char "yes"